# Creating tiles from rotated elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tiles

I have visited a page discussing the calculations required to rotate an image for tiling purposes. I am still very stuck.
I've even tried using the automated tool inside the G'MIC plugin in GIMP.

This is the single bucket I am starting with:

[image: single bucket]

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Desired result]

I need the buckets to line up when tiled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provided you're inpossession of a vector version of the bucket, I'd advise you to use Illustrator for this gig. CS6's pattern builder is made for this stuff. You might want to look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16326/how-do-i-create-a-polygon-tessellation-pattern-in-adobe-illustrator

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create a pattern or tiles from rotated elements](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17132/8708)

Answer (score 2):

For Photoshop....

- Create a selection around the upright bucket.
- Choose `Edit > Define Pattern`
- Create a new layer in the document you want the pattern applied to.
- Fill the new layer with any *any* color and then set the layer **Fill opacity** to **zero**
- Choose `Layer > Layer Style > Pattern Overlay`
- Select the bucket pattern you just defined, and click OK
- Choose `Layer > Smart Objects > Convert to Smart Object`
- Rotate the pattern smart object layer

If you find after rotation that your pattern does not cover the entire document area, simply double-click the smart object pattern layer and increase the canvas size in that document.

Unfortunately Photoshop offers no ability to rotate patterns. Hard to believe. That's a feature that should absolutely be implemented but until it is this workaround has been good for me. There's no real reason to create a pattern at a specific angle in this case. It's often easier to simply apply a straight pattern, then rotate the layer or smart object.